# localstorage alternatives for a django iframe app

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, local-storage, shopify-app

Are there any alternatives for localstorage as we are using this to store a few data. Our issue is that our app is working as an iframe in Shopify, so when testing in incognito window it denies the access of localstorage. This is the error we are getting:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document.

Can someone please suggest a solution for this issue?

Comment: Are you using chrome as browser?

Comment: Yes, I know that turning of third party disabled option works. But I am checking if there is any other wayaround

Answer (score 0):

If you are using chrome as browser, then it is possibly because you may be blocking third party cookies.

So in chrome's settings > Privacy and security > Cookies and other site data > set allow all cookies

When in incognito mode:
[image]
Disable that option showing "Block third party cookies"

Comment: We cannot do that as shopify is testing our app and they are testing in incognito and they don't disable this option while testing. I had a talk with their support about this.